# java ee ajax bind selected radio buttons to controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

i have a html table:

```
<div id="connInfoMainDiv">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Connection</td>
          <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>On</td>
          <td>
            <input type"radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="rs[0].selection"> off
            <input type"radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="rs[0].selection"> on
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" text="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

here is my java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/conn/ajax")
public String getAjaxConnInfo(@ModelAttribute("ConnForm")ConnForm connForm,
BindingResult result,
ModelMap model,
final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  .....//get data from web service
  model.addAttribute("connForm", connForm);
  return "/conn/ajax";
}
```

here is my connForm:

```
public class ConnForm {
    private List<connT> connList;
}
```

here is my connT class:

```
public class connT {
    private int connStatus = 0; // 0=off, 1,on
    private boolean radioSelected = false;
}
```

here is my ajax which does the polling:

```
$(document).read(function() {
 setInterval(getConnInfo, 2000);
});

function getConnInfo() {
  $.get("http://domain.com/conn/ajax", function(data) {
    $("#connInfoMainDiv").html(data);
  });
}
```

i implemented a ajax polling to constantly update the data on this page. what happen in the controller is it will get the data from database, set it to the object and return it to the jsp template. i previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878463/java-jstl-populate-table-data-using-ajax/17912478#comment27023726_17912478)

```
here is the problem im encountering:
- Connection is off, radio button "off" is checked
- i clicked radio button "on".
- before i could click submit, the ajax kicks in. when this happen, it updates the page and the radio button "off" is checked.
```

how can i keep the radio button "on" checked??

Comment: Could you provide the JavaScript that handles the radio click event?

Comment: hi theres no specific js that handle radio click event for ajax. basically the ajax calls the controller which reads the data, set the object, and pass it to the view jsp template.

Comment: hey sp00m, i added more codes for clarity.

Comment: Could you provide your `ConnForm` bean implementation? Only the members, no need to put the accessors (getters and setters).

Comment: hey sp00m, sorry for the late reply. i added ConnForm and ConnT class. hopefully its clearer