# Best Practice to refresh the data in JSP without refreshing the whole page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, refresh

How is it possible to refresh the data which i get from the servlet in the jsp page without refreshing the whole page.

I am not satisfied with my solution now, which is:

polling a jsp page from the server and loading it in a div container. (See following)

My jsp file would look like following:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="myList" >
    <tr>
        <td class="aligncenter">
          <span class="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option${myList.id}" value="${myList.id}"></input>
          </span></td>
        <td class="listId">${list.id}</td>
        <td>${myList.title}</td>
        <td>${myList.description}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><img style="height:40px;" src="../../app/images/food/thumbnail/${myList.imagePath}"></img></td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Know i have a method which calls a method in my controller that retrieves a this jsp file with the attributes in the model.

Then I load this jspfile in a div with jquery

```
jQuery('.myDivWhereIWantToLoadMyJspFile').load(data);
```

Is there a other possibility to refresh the data in a jsp page except websockets?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request, that is meant to be used for partial page refreshes. With ajax a request is sent to the server but the page remains the same.

Then an event is triggered when the response arrives. In response to that event we can modify parts of the page with fresh data without reloading it.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878463/java-jstl-populate-table-data-using-ajax) for an example of how to do it with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you, i also use this practice. but to my mind it seems to be a little bit uncomfortable the response would be json strings or something like else or? - so you have to rebuild your html in javascript?
or you get from the server a new jsp file which you are loading in the same div as before.

Comment: If you send the ajax request to a jsp then the response will be HTML, it does not necessarily need to be JSON - only if the request was made to a controller that returns JSON.  it's possible to take the parts that you want from the HTML reponse with jQuery and put them on the page. But other than that there is no out of the box support for ajax. The next generation view technology is JSF that solves this problem by allowing to mark parts of the page as ajax-enabled using XML tags